# $f(x)=\sqrt{a\sin^2(x) +b\cos^2(x)+c} +\sqrt{a\cos^2(x)+b\sin^2(x)+c}$, Prove that $\sqrt{a+ c} + \sqrt{b + c} \le f(x) \le 2\sqrt{\frac{a+ b}{2}+c}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inequality, jensen-inequality, karamata-inequality

$f(x) = \sqrt{a\sin^2(x) + b\cos^2(x) + c} + \sqrt{a\cos^2(x) + b\sin^2(x) + c}$

$a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Spring Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csqrt%7Ba%2Bc%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7Bb%2Bc%7D%5Cle%20f(x)%5Cle%202%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7Ba%2Bb%7D%7B2%7D%2Bc%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24f(x)%3D%5Csqrt%7Ba%5Csin%5E2(x)%2Bb%5Ccos%5E2(x)%2Bc%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7Ba%5Ccos%5E2(x)%2Bb%5Csin%5E2(x)%2Bc%7D%24&p=1), there are two quite similar questions of [The maximum and minimum values of the expression](/q/1364170) and [Finding minimum of trigonometric function](/q/2263431).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right inequality.

Since $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is a concave function, by Jensen we obtain:
$$f(x)\leq2\sqrt{\frac{a\sin^2x+b\cos^2x+c+a\cos^2x+b\sin^2x+c}{2}}=2\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{2}+c}.$$
The left inequality.

We need to prove that:
$$a+b+2c+2\sqrt{(a\sin^2x+b\cos^2x+c)(a\cos^2x+b\sin^2x+c)}\geq$$
$$\geq a+b+2c+2\sqrt{(a+c)(b+c)}$$ or
$$(a\sin^2x+b\cos^2x+c)(a\cos^2x+b\sin^2x+c)\geq(a+c)(b+c)$$ or
$$(a^2+b^2)\sin^2x\cos^2x+ab(\sin^4x+\cos^4x-1)\geq0$$ or
$$(a^2+b^2)\sin^2x\cos^2x+ab(\sin^4x+\cos^4x-(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2)\geq0$$ or
$$(a-b)^2\sin^2x\cos^2x\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

The right inequality.

By C-S $$f(x)\leq\sqrt{(1+1)(a\sin^2x+b\cos^2x+c+a\cos^2x+b\sin^2x+c)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{2(a+b+2c)}=2\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{2}+c}.$$
The left inequality.

Since $f(x)=f(-x)$ and $f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=f(x),$ we can assume that $x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right],$

which gives $\cos2x\geq0.$

Also, we can assume that $a\geq b.$

Now, after squaring of the both sides(see my previous solution) we need to prove that $$(a\sin^2x+b\cos^2x+c)(a\cos^2x+b\sin^2x+c)\geq(a+c)(b+c)$$ or
$$\ln(a\cos^2x+b\sin^2x+c)+\ln(a\sin^2x+b\cos^2x+c)\geq\ln(a+c)+\ln(b+c),$$
which is true by Karamata because $$(a+c,b+c)\succ(a\cos^2x+b\sin^2x+c,a\sin^2x+b\cos^2x+c)$$ and $\ln$ is a concave function.

Also, the left inequality i's just Karamata for the concave function $h(x)=\sqrt{x}.$

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1364219/602049) does, use the rearrangements of the [double-angle formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle_formulae) for $\cos(2x)$ to get

$$\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}, \; \; \cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

which then leads to

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(x) & = \sqrt{a\sin^2(x) + b\cos^2(x) + c} + \sqrt{a\cos^2(x) + b\sin^2(x) + c} \\
& = \sqrt{a\left(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\right) + b\left(\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}\right) + c} \;\; + \\
& \;\;\;\; \sqrt{a\left(\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}\right) + b\left(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\right) + c} \\
& = \sqrt{\left(\frac{a+b}{2}+c\right) + \left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)\cos(2x)} \;\; + \\
& \;\;\;\; \sqrt{\left(\frac{a+b}{2}+c\right) - \left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)\cos(2x)} \\
& = \sqrt{A + B\cos(2x)} + \sqrt{A - B\cos(2x)}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

where

$$A = \frac{a+b}{2}+c, \; \; B = \frac{b-a}{2} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Similar to what you did, taking the derivative of $f(x)$ and setting it to $0$ gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
0 & = \frac{-B\sin(2x)}{\sqrt{A+B\cos(2x)}}+\frac{B\sin(2x)}{\sqrt{A-B\cos(2x)}} \\
& = B\sin(2x)\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{A+B\cos(2x)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{A-B\cos(2x)}}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

There are now several possibilities. First, if $B=0$, then from \eqref{eq3A} we have $a=b$, so $f(x) = \sqrt{a+c} + \sqrt{b+c}$. Thus, it's equal to the your LHS minimum value.

With $B \neq 0$, the next possibility is that $\sin(2x)=0$, so $\cos(2x)=\pm 1$. This gives a minimum  (which can be confirmed by checking the second derivative) of $f(x) = \sqrt{a+c} + \sqrt{b+c}$, i.e., your LHS inequality.

The final possibility is that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
0 & = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{A+B\cos(2x)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{A-B\cos(2x)}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{A+B\cos(2x)}} & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{A-B\cos(2x)}} \\
A-B\cos(2x) & = A+B\cos(2x) \\
\cos(2x) & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

This gives a maximum, with using \eqref{eq2A} and \eqref{eq3A} giving the below, i.e., the RHS of your inequality

$$f(x) = 2\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{2}+c} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Answer (score 0):

My other [answer's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4607528/602049) $(2)$ and $(3)$ determine

$$f(x) = \sqrt{A + B\cos(2x)} + \sqrt{A - B\cos(2x)} \tag{1}\label{eq1B}$$

$$A = \frac{a+b}{2}+c, \; \; B = \frac{b-a}{2} \tag{2}\label{eq2B}$$

To prove the LHS inequality, use \eqref{eq2B} to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(A+B\cos(2x))(A-B\cos(2x)) & = A^2 - B^2\cos^2(2x) \\
& \ge A^2 - B^2 \\
& = \left(\frac{a+b}{2}+c\right)^2 - \left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^2 \\
& = ab + ac + bc + c^2 \\
& = (a+c)(b+c)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3B}$$

With your original $f(x)$ expression and \eqref{eq1B}, this leads to

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a+b+2c+2\sqrt{A+B\cos(2x)}\sqrt{A-B\cos(2x)} & \ge a+b+2c+2\sqrt{a+c}\sqrt{b+c} \\
\left(\sqrt{A+B\cos(2x)} + \sqrt{A-B\cos(2x)}\right)^2 & \ge \left(\sqrt{a+c} + \sqrt{b+c}\right)^2 \\
f(x) & \ge \sqrt{a+c} + \sqrt{b+c}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4B}$$

For the RHS inequality, from \eqref{eq3B} we also have $(A+B\cos(2x))(A-B\cos(2x)) \le A^2$, which similar to \eqref{eq4B} and using \eqref{eq2B}, then gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& a+b+2c+2\sqrt{A+B\cos(2x)}\sqrt{A-B\cos(2x)} \le a+b+2c+2\left(\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{2}+c}\right)^2 \\
& \left(\sqrt{A+B\cos(2x)} + \sqrt{A-B\cos(2x)}\right)^2 \le \left(\left(\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{2}+c}\right) + \left(\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{2}+c}\right)\right)^2 \\
& \sqrt{A+B\cos(2x)} + \sqrt{A-B\cos(2x)} \le \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{2}+c} + \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{2}+c} \\
& \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad f(x) \le 2\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{2}+c}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5B}$$

---

Alternatively, to get the RHS inequality, first set $g(x) = \sqrt{a\sin^2(x) + b\cos^2(x) + c}$ and $h(x) = \sqrt{a\cos^2(x) + b\sin^2(x) + c}$. Then the inequality between the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) and [quadratic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square), as shown in [HM-GM-AM-QM inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities), gives that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{g(x) + h(x)}{2} & \le \sqrt{\frac{g^2(x) + h^2(x)}{2}} \\
\frac{f(x)}{2} & \le \sqrt{\frac{a+b+2c}{2}} \\
f(x) & \le 2\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{2}+c}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6B}$$